# MOSFET (MDU1513) - two of the three source pins solder joined together

Tags: mosfet

I was trying to replace a MOSFET (MDU1513 [datasheet](https://www.magnachip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/MDU1513-1.pdf)) for a Zotac 1080Ti GPU.  The MOSFET has three source pins and one gate pin.  I was wondering if there is a problem if two of the source pins were solder joined together.  Would it cause any issue?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: If they're already connected together inside the package then it should make very little difference if they're also connected together outside the package.

Comment: No drain pin(s)? Hmm...

Comment: In the datasheet you can see the device has 8 pins, 1 pin is the gate, the 3 pins next to the gate are all connected to the source of the MOSFET. They're shorted inside the device. It does not matter if you short them again outside the device. Look carefully on the PCB, the connections will be shorted there as well.

Comment: Hi , thanks for all the inputs.  How do you know from the datasheet that the 3 source pins are connected inside the mosfet?

Answer (score 0):

This can come back and zap you very quickly. This MOSFET is probably rated at 25C with an infinite heat sink. with all of the same leads connected together. You can connect as many as you like but if they are not all connected together via a low impedance (electrical and thermal) paths your capabilities of the MOSFET are degraded. Reason the bonding connections are not zero, they have resistance and will add heat as load is applied created by the voltage drop across them. The drain is the most important because of heat transfer, the die is bounded directly to the back metal of the package which the drain pins appear to be an extension of. The source needed to be connected together mainly because of the associate bond losses. This device handles a lot of current, over 88 amps.